# Can't read Word doc into Collection properly

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

I have a custom object (Item) and i am trying to loop through a document, adding each sentence in the document as a variable of an Item and add it to an array. My problem is that the last Item i read in seems to take up every space in my array. Code below:

```
Sub Main()
'Count Variables
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

'Variables
Dim My_Question As New Question
'Dim myexcel As Object
'Dim myWB As Object
'Dim ExcelMaster As String
Dim Found As Boolean

'Array declaration
Dim Q_Coll As New Collection
'Dim MasterCodes As New Collection

i = 1
'Reads in Items and store as item objects
'Storing in Array for later sorting
For i = 1 To 3
    My_Question.Stem = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "Stem: " & My_Question.Stem

    My_Question.A = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "A: " & My_Question.A

    My_Question.B = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "B: " & My_Question.B

    My_Question.C = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "C: " & My_Question.C

    My_Question.D = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "D: " & My_Question.D

    My_Question.Master = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "Master: "; My_Question.Master

    My_Question.ICS = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "ICS: " & My_Question.ICS

    My_Question.State = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "State: " & My_Question.State

    My_Question.Key = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "Key: " & My_Question.Key

    Q_Coll.Add Item:=My_Question
Next i

For i = 1 To 3
    Debug.Print Q_Coll(i).Stem
Next i
End Sub
```

**Input**
This is a test question?
(A) Answer A
(B) Answer B
(C) Answer C
(D) Answer D

Master Code: ABC12345
ICS: 1.A.1.A
State: New
Key: B

This another question to test?
(A) Answer 1
(B) Answer 2
(C) Answer 3
(D) Answer 4

Master Code: ABC54321
ICS: 1.B.1.C
State: New
Key: A

This is the last test question?
(A) Answer A1
(B) Answer B2
(C) Answer C3
(D) Answer D4

Master Code: XYZ12345
ICS: 2.F.1.C
State: Useable
Key: D

**Debug Output**
Stem: This is a test question?

A:  (A) Answer A

B:  (B) Answer B

C:  (C) Answer C

D:  (D) Answer D

Master: Master Code: ABC12345

ICS: ICS: 1.A.1.A

State: State: New

Key: Key: B

Stem: This another question to test?

A:  (A) Answer 1

B:  (B) Answer 2

C:  (C) Answer 3

D:  (D) Answer 4

Master: Master Code: ABC54321

ICS: ICS: 1.B.1.C

State: State: New

Key: Key: A

Stem: This is the last test question?

A:  (A) Answer A1

B:  (B) Answer B2

C:  (C) Answer C3

D:  (D) Answer D4

Master: Master Code: XYZ12345

ICS: ICS: 2.F.1.C

State: State: Useable

Key: Key: D

This is the last test question?

This is the last test question?

This is the last test question?

I am printing out each string as i read it in but the final output just prints the last item over and over.

Comment: What is an `Item` object? Have you defined a class named `Item`? `Item` is used by VBA for a number of things - creating an object/class with that name is not a good idea. In any case, this is not a [mcve] - in order to test this we also need the definition of the object (an [mcve]). If that's large, create a smaller, "test case". You can use the [edit] link to add information to the original question.

Comment: Are there enough sentences in the doc for this (9x15)?

Comment: Consider using a collection rather than an array, it will make you life so much easier.   The line 'Set ItemArr(i)=Item' would become 'ItemColl.add Item'.  Collections can accessed like an array e.g. set my_item = ItemColl.Item(i).  Item is a method of the Collection class so you can see why you have been advised that using Item as a variable name is not a good idea.  You can loop over a collection using 'For Each my_item in ItemColl'

Comment: @LordAstrotrain You also need to be aware that VBA has no idea what a grammatical sentence is. For example, consider the following: *Mr. Smith spent $1,234.56 at Dr. John's Grocery Store, to buy: 10.25kg of potatoes; 10kg of avocados; and 15.1kg of Mrs. Green's Mt. Pleasant macadamia nuts.* For you and me, that would count as one sentence; for VBA it counts as 5 sentences. Basically, a VBA 'sentence' stops at the first punctuation mark.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Replacing the definition for "Question" at the top of the code with "Dim My_Question As Question" and then setting at the start of the for loop as "Set My_Question = New Question" seems to fix the output. Code below:

```
Sub Main()
'Count Variables
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

'Variables
Dim My_Question As Question
Dim Found As Boolean

'Collection declaration
Dim Q_Coll As New Collection

i = 1
'Reads in Items and store as item objects
'Storing in Collection for later sorting
For i = 1 To 15
    Set My_Question = New Question
    My_Question.Stem = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "Stem: " & My_Question.Stem

    My_Question.A = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "A: " & My_Question.A

    My_Question.B = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "B: " & My_Question.B

    My_Question.C = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "C: " & My_Question.C

    My_Question.D = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "D: " & My_Question.D

    My_Question.Master = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "Master: "; My_Question.Master

    My_Question.ICS = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "ICS: " & My_Question.ICS

    My_Question.State = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "State: " & My_Question.State

    My_Question.Key = Selection.Sentences(1).Text
    Selection.Sentences(1).Delete
    Debug.Print "Key: " & My_Question.Key

    Q_Coll.Add Item:=My_Question
Next i

For i = 1 To 15
    Debug.Print Q_Coll(i).Stem
Next i
End Sub
```